# Class is not generated from xsd using maven-jaxb2-plugin?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jaxb, xsd

I have below xsd elements. I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate sources.

```
  <xsd:element name="SearchRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" /> 
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="SearchResponse" type="ResponseType"/>


 <xsd:complexType name="ResponseType">
    //Have some complex elements here
</xsd:complexType>
```

But here i expect 3 classes to generate as below.

```
SearchRequest.java
SearchResponse.java
ResponseType.java
```

But maven-jaxb2-plugin is generating only 2 classes as below but SearchResponse class is not generated.

```
SearchRequest.java
ResponseType.java
```

My questions is why `SearchResponse.java` class is not generated? Is there any mistake in **SearchResponse** xsd element? Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Comment: Add an element responseText of type string in SearchResponse xsd and try again.

Comment: I could not get ..could u pls give me more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB will generate a class for each complex type.  If the complex type is anonymous the. The class name will be derived from the owning element.

Since `SearchResponse` is an element with a named complex type instead of a class an entry in `ObjectFactory` annotated with `@XmlElementDecl(name="SearchResponse")` will be generated.  When you unmarshal a document starting with `SearchResponse` you will get an instance of `JAXBElement<ResponseType>` back.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To generate SearchResponse, do i need to make any changes to SearchResponse xsd element? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for ur updated answer. My requirement is i have to have 3 generated classes. What can i do now? Thanks! I need SearchResponse pojo to populate and return.

Comment: @user755806 - Why is generating 3 classes a requirement?

Comment: because my web method has to return SearchResponse . else it will be JAXBElement<ResponseType>. am i right? Thnx

Comment: @user755806 - You can try this extension to see if you like the output better:  https://jaxb.java.net/2.1.2/docs/vendorCustomizations.html#simple

Comment: Ok stupid question, i have a case where some of my requests/responses are not complex  types-this classes are not generated by JAXB. How can i use them to call SOAP Web services? Example `<message name="CardManagementEP_login">
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string"> </part>
    <part name="password" type="xsd:string"> </part>
</message>`  
Thanks a lot in advance